# How to create a custom React element that can access ThemeProvider from material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

It's as simple as it sounds, I have checked everywhere, I want to be able to make a custom element that can get the theme from the parent ThemeProvider from material-ui so it can be directly integrated.
Thanks in advance and please let me know how I can make this question clearer in anyway!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you ever worked with providers and React context before? If not, that'd be a good place to start.

Comment: @JMadelaine I haven't really tried much as I don't know where to start, but I will start looking into providers and React Context, thank you!

Comment: inside any function component you can use `const theme = useTheme()`. Does that help?

Comment: @hotpink Why yes, yes it does! Please post it as an answer so I can give u the props u deserve!

Comment: There are other ways, so it would be an incomplete answer and quite frankly I think this is already sufficiently documented in the MUI docs. If you ever have a specific problem, I'll gladly address that with a proper answer, if I can.